# I have a django model but i only want to put some of my models as forms.

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

For example, lets say this is my model:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField()
    friends = models.CharField()
```

and I only want to have the friends as a form field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a **ModelForm**? If so, you set the fields you want using the `fields` variable in the `Meta` class:

```
from django import forms
from yourapp.models import Author

class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = [ "friends", ]
```

**Note:** The fields variable is a *list*, so make sure you include the trailing comma if you're only passing a single field.

Suggest that you have a read of the Django [ModelForm Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/) as well, as that way you'll get a bit ahead on all the other questions you're probably about to come up with :)